# jAutodoc Getter Template

Tags: templates, javadoc, jautodoc

I would like to set up the template to comment automatically my getter as for example:

```
int getNumberOfQuestions()
```

This should ideally give me

Recover the value of `numberOfQuestions`

So what I didn't catch is ok I can get `NumberOfQuestions` with e.g(1)
But Actually I have `${e.g(1).rsfl()}` and can't succeed to remove the split and if I remove `rsfl` I don't have the split but I loose the first letter in lower case???

Comment: I question the need to provide any documentation for getters/setters that provide no other functionality.

Comment: I understand, but sometime you work with people who are asking you to do things you don't any way to say No

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `fl` (first to lower): `${e.g(1).fl()}`

Comment: Many thanks, I thought I try that but I probably make a typing error. It's working.

Comment: Martin is the author of JAutoDoc.